# Paris at Easter

Tags: paris, public-holidays

I'm thinking of going to Paris during the Easter weekend, has anyone been before?

My specific answerable questions are:

1. Were tourist attractions such as the Eiffel Tower or the Louvre open during
   the week/weekend of Easter (any days)?
2. Were the attractions mentioned above crowded, or were wait lines normal for the average?
3. Are prices put up during Easter?

Comment: The timing of Easter may affect how crowded Paris is - this year Easter is quite late. Top attractions receive millions of visitors a year, so they’re always likely to be busy (depending on how an individual defines ‘crowded’) https://www.iau-idf.fr/fileadmin/NewEtudes/Etude_1437/KEY_FIGURES_2018-HD.pdf

Comment: Welcome new user.  The very general answer to your question is, "Paris is pretty tourist-crowded all the time, and there's, generally, not a lot of difference at any specific time of the year."  Enjoy!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I visited Paris for the second time during easter last year, it was generally slightly more crowded than the first time I went (November 2016) but this could have been down to other reasons such as the weather.

The Eiffel Tower is actually open longer on holidays like Easter, extending their opening times to midnight. [Source](http://visiteiffeltower.com/opening-days-and-hours/) And the [Louvre](https://www.louvre.fr/en/hours-admission-directions) only alters their opening times at Christmas, so is not closed either.

The attractions such as those mentioned above didn't charge more, but some street sellers may do. I didn't notice any specific price increases.

Comment: @cait You're welcome, enjoy the trip!